# How to get Étoilé on ubuntu

Tags: desktop-environments

Étoilé is a Desktop environment. I want on on my ubuntu 12.04 computer but how?

Can you Please Help me With it.

Comment: They haven't mentioned the [build](http://etoileos.com/downloads/installrelease/ubuntu/) for 12.04 yet  and they are referring it as Developer built and less a Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Please note:

> WARNING: As it stands now, Etoile is more or less a development
>   environment and not a desktop environment. We have no working theme
>   since we are still in the process of migrating from our Camaelon theme
>   engine to the new one bundled with GNUstep. User-oriented applications
>   such as Melodie can fail to launch or behave correctly because their
>   development have been put on hold. We advise you not to use the
>   session support built into Étoilé, but rather write Étoilé code inside
>   another environment such as GNOME or KDE.

Taken from the Etoile website.

### How to install (trunk)

Etoile is a of a tough call on Ubuntu, but I'll try to guide you in the right direction. Please note a few things though:

- I have not installed Etoile myself.
- Etoile is not officially supported on Ubuntu.
- The instructions provided are outdated.

The dependencies are posted here: http://etoileos.com/downloads/installtrunk/ubuntu/ and the instructions are here: http://etoileos.com/downloads/installtrunk/

I would have liked to include instructions here, but as this project would be best installed on your system using the trunk version I would suggest you follow what instructions they have on their site directly (the instructions will be kept up to date).